# How to access functions in libgromacs.so with ctypes in Python?

Tags: python, ctypes

[Gromacs](https://www.gromacs.org) is a software package for molecular modelling. I want to access some functions exported in `libgromacs.so` library using `ctypes` in Python.

The sample function `open_xtc` is obviously exported in `libgromacs.so`:

```
$ nm -D --demangle libgromacs.so | grep open_xtc
0000000000d98e30 T open_xtc(char const*, char const*)
```

The following Python code, however, for some reasons doesn't work

```
import ctypes
LGMX = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libgromacs.so')
LGMX.open_xtc
```

and returns

```
AttributeError: libgromacs.so: undefined symbol: open_xtc
```

How can I access functions in `libgromacs.so`?

Comment: Remember that part where you had to demangle the name with `--demangle` to see "open_xtc"? `ctypes` isn't going to mangle the name for you.

Comment: If the name is mangled, it is probably a C++ function. “C”types, doesn’t support C++, but you might get away with using a mangled name on a global function.

Comment: Thank you! As a temporary solution, I'm using `nm` to get the mangled object name for which I know the original name. Then, `getattr` does the trick. Reading more on C++ symbol names mangling I have no illusions that handling dynamically mangled names in a code is not really possible now.